# supercollider - access buffer information inside a `Pbind` that uses a buffer array

Tags: arrays, audio, buffer, supercollider

---

## in brief

**i have an array of buffers; those are passed to a synth at random using a `Pbind` ; i need to access info on the current buffer from within the `Pbind` but I need help doing that !**

---

## explanation of the problem

i have loaded an array of buffers containing samples. those samples must be played in a random order (and at random intervals, but that's for later). to do so, i pass those buffers to a synth inside a `Pbind`. i want to set the `\dur` key to be the length of the current buffer being played. the thing is, that **i can't find a way to access info on the current buffer from within the `Pbind`**. i have tried using `Pkey`, `Pfset` and `Plambda`, but to no success.

does somebody know how to do this ???

---

## code

the sounds are played using:

```
SynthDef(\player, {
  /*
    play a file from a buffer
    out: the output channel
    bufnum: the buffer to play
  */
  arg out=0, bufnum;
  Out.ar(
    out,
    PlayBuf.ar(1, bufnum, BufRateScale.kr(bufnum),  doneAction: Done.freeSelf)) ! 2
  )
}).add;
```

the buffers are loaded in an array:

```
path = PathName.new("/path/to/files");
bufferArray = Array.new(100);
path.filesDo({
  arg file;
  bufferArray.add( Buffer.read(s, file.fullPath) );
});
```

my `Pbind` pattern works like this:

- i define a `\buffer` value which is a single buffer from the array
- i pass this `\buffer` to my synth
- i then try to calculate its duration (`\dur`) by dividing the number of frames of the buffer by its sample rate. **this is what i can't seem to get right**

```
p = Pbind(
  \buffer, Prand(bufferArray, inf),
  \instrument, \player,
  \bufnum, Pkey(\buffer),
  \dur, (Pkey(\buffer.numFrames) / Pkey(\buffer.sampleRate))
)
```

---

thanks in advance for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

## solution to the problem: how to access buffer information inside a `Pbind` pattern

after **hours** of searching, i've found a solution to this problem on [the supercollider forum](https://scsynth.org/t/using-pkey-pswitch-to-get-buffer-information/1167), and i'm posting my own solution in case others are looking on here, like i was !

---

### define a global array of buffers

this isn't compulsory, but it allows to only create the buffer array once; the array is created asynchronously using the `action` parameter of `Buffer.read()`, which allows to trigger a function once the buffer is loaded:

```
var path;
Buffer.freeAll;  // avoid using all buffers in server
path = PathName.new("/path/to/sound/files");
~bufferArray = Array.new(100);
path.filesDo({
  // add the buffer to `~bufferArray` asynchronously
  arg file;
  b = Buffer.read(s, file.fullPath, action: {
    arg buffer;
    ~bufferArray.add( buffer );
  })
});
```

### play the synth and use `Pfunc` to access buffer information inside of the `Pbind`

this is the solution per se:

- define a `Pbind` pattern which activates a synth to play the buffer.
- inside that, define a `\buffer` variable to hold the current buffer.
- then, access data on that buffer inside of a `Pfunc`. this generates an argument containing the last event in the `Pbind`. using this event, the buffer data can be accessed

```
p = Pbind(
  \buffer, Prand(~bufferArray, inf),  // randomly access one buffer inside of the array
  \instrument, \player,
  \bufnum, Pfunc { arg event; event[\buffer] },  // define a `Pfunc` function to access the previous event containing a `\buffer` variable
  \dur, Pfunc { arg event; event[\buffer].numFrames / event[\buffer].sampleRate }  // duration
);
p.play;
```

---

see the original answer on the supercollider forum for more details !